# Get-go attitude vs. go-getter

Tags: idioms

I want to write a recommendation for a friend in LinkedIn, and I want to emphasise that he was a real hard worker.

So, does "he has a get-go attitude" means that someone is a "go-getter"?

Comment: A *go-getter* has a *go-getting attitude*.

Comment: You can also say "He's got a *can-do* attitude", or "He's a *self-starter*", etc.

Comment: Sorry @Dan Bron, missed your comment in my haste - you should have posted!

Comment: @LittleEva No problem at all!

Comment: _Get-go_ and _go-get_ are different idioms. _From the get-go_ means 'from the very beginning', so _get-go_ means 'beginning'. _Go get_, on the other hand, means to take action (go) and achieve (get) something in return. It's a serial verb construction, _Go get me another brewski, would you?_ A _go-getter_ is an old term for what is now called a self-motivating overachiever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **can-do** *adjective*: informal
>
> characterized by or exhibiting a determination or willingness to take action and achieve results.
>
> • "I like his can-do attitude"
>
> See, google.com “can-do” [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=can-do+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=can+do+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0i22i30l5.0.0.1.170001...........0.ys4-tn3vyIA&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: +1, Draconar, thank you for the selection! You should try to let your post "ride" for awhile so more community can get involved. You'll get more comments and answers and more rep if you don't hurry your selection. :-)

Comment: I'm confused here.. but does get-go even exist? or is the correct one go-getter?

Comment: @Draconar I've never heard _get-go_.

Comment: A "**Go-getter**" describes a personal quality very similar to a "**can-do**" attitude. You could say that a person with a can-do attitude is a real go-getter.

Comment: @Draconar _Get-go_ does exist, but it means something completely different: ‘beginning’. You can say, for example, “This project has been plagued by hardware problems _from the get-go_”. It does not exist in any sense that has anything to do with being a _go-getter_.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, "This project has been plagued by hardware problems *from the get-go* and will require *a real go-getter* with a *can-do attitude*!”.